# Is there a tool that allows me to have the sound from a certain app play from a specific direction?

Tags: audio

The title says it all. Basically, when I game while on a teams call with my friend, I want the sound from the game to be played normally, and my friend's voice to come from a comfortable direction, like from behind, instead of it "coming from everywhere" which confuses my hearing. Is it possible somehow? Thank you!

Edit: To clarify, I have both the game and teams open, and I want just the sound from teams to play from the direction I choose.

Edit 2: My audio setup is simply my headphones connected directly to my desktop's sound card, but I do own an external sound card which I'm not using. Sorry for my ignorance guys, and thank you for your patience and support!

Comment: On Windows 10??

Comment: It's only possible if the game supports such an option.

Comment: Sounds like a job for https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @harrymc Microsoft Teams is not a game.

Comment: @Gantendo thank you, I'll try there!

Comment: @M4dMel: By "direction", do you mean a (loud)speaker? We'll need more information about your audio hardware setup to answer that.

Comment: @harrymc Right, my bad. I hope I answered in Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

You may connect to the external sound card a speaker
(hopefully recognized by Windows).
The speaker itself can be physically placed anywhere that you like.

You could set this speaker as the audio output for Teams.
If this doesn't work for Teams, you could force it with a
[VB-Audio Virtual App](https://vb-audio.com/Cable/).

(The description above is (too) simple, as there will surely be
unforeseen technical problems, but you may evoke these again on
our site.)